# In new Spring Authorization Server how is a custom grant implemented

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

In the process of migrating from the deprecated Spring spring-security-oauth2 to spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server 0.2.1 [Spring Authorization Server](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server)

A custom grant type was implemented on the old oauth server by extending AbstractTokenGranter and adding to the list of existing token granters.

```
    private TokenGranter createTokenGranter(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) {
        CustomTokenGranter customTokenGranter = new CustomTokenGranter(endpoints.getTokenServices(), endpoints.getClientDetailsService(),
                endpoints.getOAuth2RequestFactory(), JWT_TOKEN, userClient, jwtService, messageAccessor);
        List<TokenGranter> tokenGranters = asList(endpoints.getTokenGranter(), customTokenGranter);
        return new CompositeTokenGranter(tokenGranters); }
```

TokenGrant has been removed in new oauth server.

What would be the approach to create a custom grant type in new oauth server?